# Unitary Diagonalization of matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & i & 0 \\
-i & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since this matrix is Hermitian, we know that it should be unitarily diagonalizable. But when I try to solve the characteristic polynomial, it turns to be $-t^3+2t^2+2t-2$, I have difficulty guessing one of the roots. Can anyone help? Or did I make some mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Still, the characteristic polynomial is correct, but [its roots are complicated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((0,i,0),(-i,0,1),(0,1,2))) again.

Comment: Also, as you can see in the Wolfram Alpha link, checking if things like characteristic polynomial, eigenvalues, eigenvectors and diagonalization matrices are correct can be easily checked there.

Comment: Thanks, I will leave it blank then!

Comment: The only sensical hermitian variation of your matrix I can think of is obtained by substituting the $2$ by a zero, then the polynomial is $2t - t^3$.